# Twilio Conversations SDK hard limit

Tags: twilio

I am developing an online therapy application using Twilio Conversations SDK.

Whenever a Patient is created, a new Conversation is created with the Patient & the Psy as Participants, so eventually I run into the hard limit of 1000 conversations per Participant, and since a Psy can keep receiving Patients and there's no real way to know whether the therapy with a Patient is over.

Is there a way to have more than 1000 Conversations linked to a single identity?

I thought about two possibilities, but not convinced by either:

1. Create infinite IDs linked to a single Psy and use the Id1, Id2, etc.. As identities all pointing to the same Psy. Ideally this solves the problem but I'd have to maintain multiple WebSockets because to create the Twilio Conversations client I need to provide an Id and in this case, I'd have to juggle multiple.
2. Periodically cleaning the unused Conversations by removing the Psy participant from them, effectively leaving place for adding it to newer ones. This is complicated because if the Psy decides to visit an old Conversation, it'll throw an error.

Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: Did you find your answer? Im experimenting with twilio aswell

Comment: Not quite, we can't increase the conversation limit, but we can use timers to make conversations transition from active -> inactive -> closed. In closed state they no longer count as a conversation a user is part of, so despite they exist, they can no longer be opened and that "slot" is free, so the identity can be added in a new conversation: https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/states-timers